# Kendo Grid - inserting new object which has foreign columns fails

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid

I am facing a serious problem since 2 days. I updated my kendo framework version to the latest and since, a problem appears on inserting new items in kendo grid. This problem has not been existing before.

In my grid, I have a list of "Rack" objects. This "rack" object has two foreign column ; "room" and "customer"

When I want to insert a new rack, it fails because the controller says "room and customer info should not be null". So my grid doesn't send anymore the foreign columns info to my controller.

Here is my code:

Rack.aspx

```html
<%:
    Html.Kendo().Grid<dc.Models.Configuration.Rack>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_NAME).Title("Name");
        
        //columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_ROOM).Title("Room").ClientTemplate("#if(!data.EQU_ROOM){#''#}else{# #=data.EQU_ROOM.ROO_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.EQU_ROOM.ROO_NAME# #}#").EditorTemplateName("RoomEditor");
        //columns.Bound(r => r.RAC_CUSTOMER).Title("Customer").ClientTemplate("#if(!data.RAC_CUSTOMER){#''#}else{# #=data.RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_NAME# #}#").EditorTemplateName("CustomerEditor");
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_PROVIDER).Title("Provider");
        columns.ForeignKey(r => r.EQU_ROOM, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["rooms"], "ROO_ID", "ROO_DATA_CENTER").ClientTemplate("#if(!data.EQU_ROOM){#''#}else{# #=data.EQU_ROOM.ROO_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.EQU_ROOM.ROO_NAME# #}#").EditorTemplateName("RoomEditor")
            .Title("rooms").Width(150);
        columns.ForeignKey(r => r.RAC_CUSTOMER, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["customers"], "CUS_ID", "CUS_DATA_CENTER").ClientTemplate("#if(!data.RAC_CUSTOMER){#''#}else{# #=data.RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_NAME# #}#").EditorTemplateName("CustomerEditor")
            .Title("customer").Width(150);
        
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_MODEL).Title("Model");
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_REFERENCE).Title("Reference");
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_INTERNAL_REFERENCE).Title("Immo ID");
        columns.Bound(r => r.EQU_START_UP_DATE).Title("Start Date").EditorTemplateName("DateEditor").ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(data.EQU_START_UP_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy')#");
        columns.Bound(r => r.RAC_WIDTH).Title("Width (cm)");
        columns.Bound(r => r.RAC_DEPTH).Title("Depth (cm)");
        columns.Bound(r => r.RAC_UNITS_NUMBER).Title("Units number");
        
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
    })
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)) 
    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gridScrollableHeight"])))
    .Sortable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); toolbar.Excel(); })
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("DAFYDAC - RACK List.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Home")).AllPages(true)
     )
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gridPageSize"]))
        .Model(model => { 
            model.Id(r => r.EQU_ID); 
            model.Field(p => p.EQU_ROOM).Editable(true);

            model.Field(p => p.RAC_CUSTOMER).Editable(true);
        })
        //.Events(events => events
        //.RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd_Grid_Equipements")
        //.Error("onError")
        //)
        
        .Read(read => read.Action("Racks_Read", "Configuration"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Racks_Create", "Configuration"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Racks_Update", "Configuration"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Racks_Destroy", "Configuration"))
    )
    
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gridSize"] })

 %>
```

RoomEditor.ascx

```html
<%: Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("EQU_ROOM")
    .DataValueField("ROO_ID")
    .DataTextField("ROO_DATA_CENTER")
    .OptionLabel("Select a room")
    .Template("#if (!data.ROO_NAME) { #Select a room# } else{ # #=data.ROO_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.ROO_NAME# # } #")
    .ValueTemplate("#if (!data.ROO_NAME) { #Select a room# } else{ # #=data.ROO_DATA_CENTER.DAT_NAME# - #=data.ROO_NAME# # } #")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["rooms"])
    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = true})
%>
```

ConfigurationController.cs

```html
public ActionResult Racks_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Rack rack)
{
    ModelState.Remove("RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_ROOM.ROO_SENSOR_TEMPO.SENSOR_START_UP_DATE");
    ModelState.Remove("RAC_CUSTOMER.CUS_ROOM.ROO_SENSOR_HYGRO.SENSOR_START_UP_DATE");
    ModelState.Remove("EQU_START_UP_DATE");
    ModelState.Remove("EQU_ROOM.ROO_SENSOR_HYGRO.SENSOR_START_UP_DATE");
    ModelState.Remove("EQU_ROOM.ROO_SENSOR_TEMPO.SENSOR_START_UP_DATE");
     
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            RackRepository.Instance.Add(rack);
            var results = new[] { rack };
            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
 
            return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
            {
                Errors = "An error occured! " + e
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
        {
            Errors = "An error occured! " + string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage))
        });
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)));
        //throw new Exception("Invalid model in Col_Create");
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why the form doesn't send foreign columns info to the controller?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the columns as being foreign keys:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName")
            .Title("Category").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(150);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
```

Comment: I tried out this option but unfortunately, I got the same behaviour .

Comment: Would you mind posting the source where you did the fk binding?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post with foreign column changes. Please see above.